# Как получить путь до каждого элемента каталога?

Tags: python, pyqt5, файловая-система, ос

Как получить абсолютный путь к каждому выбранному файлу в каталоге, при том. что каждый файл находится в разных подкаталогах?

```
    ...

    self.dir = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, "choose directory")
    self.ws_dir.setPlainText(self.dir)
    if self.dir:
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(self.dir):
            for file_name in files:
                if file_name.endswith(".ws"):
                    self.WS_list.addItem(file_name)   

ob_list = [self.WS_list.item(row).text() for row in
           range(self.WS_list.count())]
 
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пожалуйста, всегда предоставляйте минимально-воспроизводимый пример.

Попробуйте так:

```
...

def select_ws(self):
    self.dir = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, "choose directory")

    self.textEdit.setPlainText(self.dir)
    if self.dir:
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(self.dir):
            for file_name in files:
                if file_name.endswith(".png"):   # !!! установите свое ".ws"
                
                    path = os.path.join(root, file_name)                        # !!! +++
#                        self.listWidget.addItem(file_name)
                    self.listWidget.addItem(path)                               # !!! +++

...
```

---

```
import sys
import os
import pandas as pd
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit()
        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget()

        vbox = QVBoxLayout(self)
        vbox.addWidget(self.textEdit) 
        vbox.addWidget(self.listWidget)        
        
        self.select_ws()
        self.process()
        
    def select_ws(self):
        self.dir = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, "choose directory")

        self.textEdit.setPlainText(self.dir)
        if self.dir:
            for root, dirs, files in os.walk(self.dir):
                for file_name in files:
                    if file_name.endswith(".png"):                          # !!! установите свое ".ws"
                    
                        path = os.path.join(root, file_name)                        # !!! +++
#                        self.listWidget.addItem(file_name)
                        self.listWidget.addItem(path)                               # !!! +++

    def process(self): 
        list_item = [self.listWidget.item(row).text() for row in  range(self.listWidget.count())] 
        #print(*list_item, sep='\n')
        
        data = pd.DataFrame(dict(
            Путь=[self.dir], 
            Список=[list_item]))                                                         
        print(data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: S.Nick, спасибо, обещаю исправится в будущем

Comment: @RishatMukhtarov пожалуйста

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
for folderName, subfolders, filenames in os.walk('C:\\Users\\filimonovaa\\Desktop'):
    print(f'Текущая папка - {folderName}')

    for subfolder in subfolders:
        print(f'Подпапка папки {folderName} : {subfolder}')
        pass
    for filename in filenames:
        print(f'Файл в папке {folderName} : {filename}')
        pass
    print('')
```

В консоли примерно так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: tomato-magnet-regulato, спасибо.